# Raspberry Pi Wireless Access Point with Proxy

Tags: pi-3, networking, wireless

I'm thinking of using my Pi3 (Model B) as a Wireless Access Point - I've seen lots of tutorials on them and I've heard that the Pi3 has AP compatibility built in!

If I decide to go ahead on this project and turn my Pi into a Wireless Access Point. I would like to have it going through a proxy, then going to the internet.

I have clients which will be connecting which currently don't support connecting to a proxy locally, so I'd like them to be able to connect to my Pi's Wireless Access Point, which will automatically forward them through the proxy server.

I've been researching this and I cannot find anything online about how to forward traffic from the Pi Wireless Access Point through the proxy, then through to the internet...

Comment: There are many questions that cover the topics "Wireless AP" and Proxy. Example https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/243/is-it-possible-to-set-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wireless-router?rq=1

Comment: You may want to consider your bandwidth requirements before you go ahead with this.